# ICE Connectivity Check - STUN Binding Responses through TURN

Tags: webrtc, stun, turn

Let's assume we have a local and remote candidates as follows:

local candidate - `relay UDP 1.2.3.4 40000`

remote candidate - `srflx UDP 192.0.0.1 50000`

This describes the following topology:

```
[ Device A <-> NAT <-> TURN ] <-> [ NAT <-> Device B ]
```

From the RFC:

```
The agent constructs a candidate pair whose local candidate equals
the mapped address of the response, and whose remote candidate equals
the destination address to which the request was sent.
```

As far as I understand, the `Device A` will send a STUN binding from its TURN relay to the server reflexive transport address of `Device B`. `Device B` will see the `relayed-transport-address` of the TURN server, put that in an `XOR-MAPPED-ADDRESS` field, and send the response back.

When `Device A` attempts to determine of this was a valid connectivity check, it examines the response against its local/remote candidates.

For the **local** candidate check:

It looks at the `XOR-MAPPED-ADDRESS` of the STUN response, which in this case is `1.2.3.4 40000`. This is the address of the source that Device B sees the message coming from. This matches its local candidate, thus we are good here.

For the **remote** candidate check:

How does `Device A` check that the `remote candidate equals the destination address to which the request was sent.`?

As far as I know, this is a transport address only known to the TURN server that is configured during the allocation/permission phase. If I had to guess, I assume it has something to do with the SEND INDICATION containing the `XOR-PEER-ADDRESS`.

i.e.

```
if (local candidate == XOR-MAPPED-ADDRESS &&
    remote candidate == XOR-PEER-ADDRESS)
       pair is valid
```

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the definition of valid is decoupled from the validity of the response. That can be checked by validating the message integrity and matching the transaction id. If you get a response that is valid in that sense you construct the valid pair.

Now...

> This matches its local candidate, thus we are good here.

This matches the local address of the relay candidate.

> For the remote candidate check:

You have been sending the  stun message via the TURN server specifying a xor-peer-address in the send indication and also receive a xor-peer-address in the data indication of the response.

See also https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5245#section-7.1.3.2.2 for full detail. It is a bit vague since TURN is specified somewhere else.

Comment: I believe ‘destination address to which the response was sent’ is eluding to the XOR-PEER-ADDRESS. That all makes sense.